# Spectrum of the product of two matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given $A, B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, $A$ is invertible and has strictly negative real eigenvalues,  $B$ has real non-positive eigenvalues. Does the product $A^{-1}B $ have a nonnegative spectrum?

I have tried several examples and I get  nonnegative spectrum but is it in general true and how can we proof this? Below is an example.

For example: $A=\begin{bmatrix}-1.7295 & 0.2633\\ 0.2 &-0.8 \end{bmatrix}$, $B=\begin{bmatrix}-0.1913& 0.1674\\0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$.
The eigenvalues of $A$ are $-1.7831, -0.7464$ and the eigenvalues of $B$ are $-0.1913,0$.

$A^{-1}B=\begin{bmatrix}0.1150 & -0.1006\\0.0288 &-0.0255 \end{bmatrix}$ and the eigenvalues are $0,0.0898$.

Answer (score 1):

Try $A=\pmatrix{-1&1\cr0&-1\cr}$, $B=\pmatrix{-1&0\cr3&-1\cr}$.

Comment: Or $A=\pmatrix{-1&4\\ 0&-1},\ B=\pmatrix{-1&0\\ 1&-1}$. In this case $A^{-1}B=\pmatrix{-3&4\\ -1&1}$ has an entirely real spectrum, but both eigenvalues are equal to $-1$.